# Como inserir DIV com campos de input dentro do DIV usando jquery ou javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Tenho um formulario simples com botão adicionar que quando eu clico ele adiciona 3 inputs de texto:

```
<form method="POST">
  <div id="ingredientes">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
  <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>

<script>
const adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");
const ingredientes = document.getElementById("ingredientes");
adicionar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  let ing = document.createElement("input");
  ing.name = "ingredientes[]";
  ing.placeholder = "Ex: Cebola";
  ing.type="text";
  let qtd = document.createElement("input");
  qtd.name = "qtd[]";
  qtd.placeholder = "Ex: ¹/² colher de café";
  qtd.type="text";
  let pre = document.createElement("input");
  pre.name = "ingredientes[]";
  pre.placeholder = "Ex: Picada";
  pre.type="text";
  ingredientes.appendChild(ing);
  ingredientes.appendChild(qtd);
  ingredientes.appendChild(pre);
});
</script>
```

Mas agora gostaria que ao adicionar, os 3 inputs ficassem dentro do Div, deveria inserir assim:

```
<div id="ingredientes">
  <div>
    <input name="quantidade[]" placeholder="Ex: 1 colher de sopa" type="text">
    <input name="ingredientes[]" placeholder="Ex: Cebola" type="text">
    <input name="preparo[]" placeholder="Ex: Picada" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");
const ingredientes = document.querySelector("#ingredientes");
adicionar.addEventListener("click", function (event) {  
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  let ing = document.createElement("input");
  ing.name = "ingredientes[]";
  ing.placeholder = "Ex: Cebola";
  ing.type="text";
  let qtd = document.createElement("input");
  qtd.name = "qtd[]";
  qtd.placeholder = "Ex: ¹/² colher de café";
  qtd.type="text";
  let pre = document.createElement("input");
  pre.name = "ingredientes[]";
  pre.placeholder = "Ex: Picada";
  pre.type="text";  
  div.appendChild(ing);
  div.appendChild(qtd);
  div.appendChild(pre);
  ingredientes.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div id="ingredientes">
   
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="adicionar">Adicionar</button>
  <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Muito simples, é só você utilizar o `document.createElement("div");` e adicionar todos os inputs dentro da `div` criada. Depois disso é só dar um `append`, colocando a `div` criada dentro da `div #ingredientes`.

Espero ter ajudado, bons estudos.

Comment: opa, valeu, mas na verdade, acho q a pergunta minha não ficou mt clara, os 3 inputs tem que ficar dentro de um div. cada 3 inputs ficam dentro de um div

Comment: Opa, vou fazer a alteração no código

Comment: Da uma olhada agora Leandro.

Comment: Era o que precisava, valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$(div).append('<div>')

$(div).append(input)

$(div).append('</div>')
```

Comment: Nesse post tem dicas legais para iniciantes em jQuery https://saibamaiz.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/5-dicas-para-comecar-bem-com-jquery/